# Controlar excepción en asignación de escala de ejes chart c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, excepciones

tengo una aplicación la cual genera gráficos de una base de datos. Las escalas se ajustan automáticamente al seleccionar el punto de acceso de datos, pero para poder investigar mas a fondo con el gráfico los datos, he configurado un ajuste de escala mediante dos comboBox y una trackBar, el tema está en que si se selecciona un valor minimo de eje en la escala mayor que el mayor del punto de datos salta una excepción que no puedo controlar, y no se como controlarla o acceder al valor máximo del punto de datos.

Este es mi código:

```
  private void changeCbY2GrafMinMin(object sender, EventArgs e) //evento que se desencadena al cambiar el comboBox que recoge el valor mínimo del eje
    {


            try
            {

                //si el valor mínimo a introducir es mayor que el valor máximo del chart
                if (int.Parse(cbY2MinGrafMinutal.Text) > chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY2.Maximum) //intento controlar que no sea mayor el valor mínimo introducido que el valor máximo del eje
                {
                    MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "DEBE SELECCIONAR DOS VALORES ACORDES, VALOR MINIMO Y MÁXIMO CORRECTOS, SELECCIONE PRIMERO UN VALOR MÁXIMO", "FALLO", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    cbY2MaxGrafMinutal.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    cbY2MinGrafMinutal.SelectedIndex = -1;
                }
                else
                {


                    tbY2GrafMin.Minimum = int.Parse(cbY2MinGrafMinutal.Text.Trim()); //asigno el valor minimo a la trackBar


                    chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY2.Minimum = int.Parse(cbY2MinGrafMinutal.Text); //le asigno el valor mínimo al eje del chart con el valor del comboBox 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            //intento controlar alguna excepción pero no salta aqui
                MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "DEBE SELECCIONAR DOS VALORES ACORDES, VALOR MINIMO Y MÁXIMO CORRECTOS" + ex, "FALLO", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                cbY2MaxGrafMinutal.SelectedIndex = -1;
                cbY2MinGrafMinutal.SelectedIndex = -1;

            }

        }
```

Pero la excepción me salta en  application.run del método main y no tengo explicación por que a veces me salta y otras no dependiendo del gráfico pues tengo varios en la aplicación, pero el código es exactamente el mismo. ¿Cómo podría controlar esta excepción?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la pila de llamadas

```
 System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Excepción no controlada</Description><AppDomain>SequoDataCosentinoSil1.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Objeto de eje: el valor mínimo del eje es mayor que el valor mayor de punto de datos.</Message><StackTrace>   en System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.EstimateAxis(Double&amp;amp; minimumValue, Double&amp;amp; maximumValue, Boolean autoMaximum, Boolean autoMinimum)
    en System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.EstimateAxis()
    en System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetDefaultAxesValues()
    en System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetData(Boolean initializeAxes, Boolean checkIndexedAligned)
    en System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.ReCalcInternal()
    en System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPicture.Paint(Graphics graph, Boolean paintTopLevelElementOnly)
    en System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    en System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
    en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message&amp;amp; m)
    en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
    en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.InvalidOperationException: Objeto de eje: el valor mínimo del eje es mayor que el valor mayor de punto de datos.
    en System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.EstimateAxis(Double&amp;amp; minimumValue, Double&amp;amp; maximumValue, Boolean autoMaximum, Boolean autoMinimum)
    en System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.EstimateAxis()
    en System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetDefaultAxesValues()
    en System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetData(Boolean initializeAxes, Boolean checkIndexedAligned)
    en System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.ReCalcInternal()
    en System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPicture.Paint(Graphics graph, Boolean paintTopLevelElementOnly)
    en System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    en System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
    en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message&amp;amp; m)
    en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
    en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
 Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException' en System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll
 Objeto de eje: el valor mínimo del eje es mayor que el valor mayor de punto de datos.

 El programa '[19288] SequoDataSil1.exe: Seguimiento de programa' terminó con código 0 (0x0).
 El programa '[19288] SequoDataSil1.exe' terminó con código -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: Este error siempre es en Debug?

Comment: Si te digo la verdad no lo he probado en release, al final he obtado por dejar desactivado los controles de valor minimo y activarlos cuando se seleccione un valor máximo, así he solucionado el posible salto de la excepción

Comment: Puede ser que la exception salte en debug porque tenes activado la arroje. Pero en release funcione bien

Comment: Que es la arroje? Voy a probarlo

Comment: que Lance la excepcion. como te esta pasando

Comment: No te había entendido, lo probaré, gracias.